# Populating dynamic values in Javascript google map using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, get

I am a new bee who has got lil knowledge of Javascript.I have a script that loads google maps using the given values of longitude and latitude.See below:

**MY Javascript:**

```
  function load()
{
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.789397, -2.255003),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  ..........................
  .........................
   .........................
}
```

I am using PHP and want to dynamically populate the values of longitude and latitude using the GET method from the URL.How can i achieve this??And how can I replace 54.789397 and -2.255003 values with the one I get from the $_GET variables???

Comment: @Salman.I am trying to figure out how can i achieve this as i am new bee and have got no knowledge of JS.I have tried JQUERY to retrieve values but it didnt help.That is why,i am asking for help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $_GET['lat'] ?>, <?php echo $_GET['lng'] ?>)`

should set you on your way.